# PHP Generate QR Code

Tags: php, html, qr-code

I am using the PHP QR code library from 'http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/'.
It is working when using 1 parameter, however when I add an additional parameter it is not generating a QR code at all. My code is as follows -

```
<?php 
// generateQR.php
include('C:\xampp\htdocs\phpqrcode\qrlib.php'); 

$param = $_GET['address']; 
$param2 = $_GET['amount'];

QRcode::png("bitcoin:".$param."?amount=".$param2);

?>
```

and main class below

```
echo '<img src="generateQR.php?address='.$newOrderaddress.'?amount='.$order_amountbtc.'"/>';
```

There are no errors thrown, it is simply not outputting a QR code using the above. If I only pass 1 variable, it is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your URL is malformed.

When sending multiple `GET` parameters in a URL, they need to be separated with ampersands i.e.

`http://domain.com/page?var1=1&var2=2`

You need to replace the `?` in the URL before `amount` with a `&` so it becomes `echo '<img src="generateQR.php?address='.$newOrderaddress.'&amount='.$order_amountbtc.'"/>'`